# When showing a view controller in a UINavigation setup from a table cell accessory, how do I know which table cell it came from?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller which has (amongst others) one view controller that contains a `UITableView` with a basic `UITableViewCell`. The `UITableViewCell` has a disclosure indicator for the accessory. This table contains the contacts for a user.

I created a new view controller 'view contact', which allows you to see the details of a contact. I right click and dragged from the disclosure indicator (although I feel like it went from the whole table cell) in the prototype cell to the new view controller and chose 'show'.

This all works, when I run it, I can tap on the contact and it navigates to the view contact page. The problem is, I don't know how to tell which cell sent me there to know which contact's details to display!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two ways to go about it.
You have chosen one of the way, the 'segue' way. Other way is to do it programatically and listen to TableViewDelegate methods.

**Segue Way**
You need your `TableViewController` to pass data to `ViewContactViewController` on press of cell. Because you have used segue, you need to hold on `ViewContactViewController` before it appears on screen.
Enter  `prepareForSegue:sender:` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue).

In this method, get hold of the viewcontroller, and pass the required data to it.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showContact"]) {
        ViewContactViewController *contactViewController = [segue destinationViewController]; // get hold of destination VC             
        contactViewController.contact = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]; // use indexPathForSelectedRow to get hold of the indexpath of selected Cell. The data can be retrieved from the datasource array and passed on                     
    }
}
```

Assumptions in above code:
1. `showContact` is defined as name of the show segue.
2. ViewContactViewController has a public property, `contact`.
3. `self.contacts` is the contacts data array that is used in tableview datasource methods.